# Prevent python imports compiling

Tags: python, import, compilation

I have have a python file that imports a few frequently changed python files. I have had trouble with the imported files not recompiling when I change them. How do I stop them compiling?

Comment: They should recompile, so I would look into why they don't first.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Permissions error? E.g. if the source .py is read-only, some say the resulting .pyc bytecode is read-only, which makes it hard to overwrite...

Comment: They're **not** recompiling and you want to **stop** them from recompiling?  That makes very little sense.  They're not recompiling -- what are you "stopping"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible - its the way Python works. The best you could do, I think, is to have some kind of automated script which deletes `*.pyc` files at first. Or you could have a development module which automatically compiles all imports - try the `compile` module.

I've personally not had this trouble before, but try checking the timestamps on the files. You could try running `touch` on all the Python files in the directory. (`find -name \\*.py -exec touch \\{\\} \\;`)

Comment: compileall.compile_dir with force = True looks like it should do the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some modules which might help you:

The py_compile module (http://effbot.org/librarybook/py-compile.htm) will allow you to explicitly compile modules (without running them like the 'import' statement does).

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("my_module.py")
```

Also, the compileall module (http://effbot.org/librarybook/compileall.htm) will compile all the modules found in a directory.

```
import compileall
compileall.compile_dir(".", force=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.6, you should be able to supply the -B option.

Comment: Or `set PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` in the environment.

Comment: Or "Py_DontWriteBytecodeFlag = 1;" in your source-code if embedding the interpreter. That's a global int declared in pydebug.h.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [compileall](http://docs.python.org/library/compileall.html)

> compileall.compile_dir(dir[,
>   maxlevels[, ddir[, force[, rx[,
>   quiet]]]]])
>
> Recursively descend the directory tree named by dir, compiling all .py
>   files along the way.